# Instantaneous Phase in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, phase

I have a signal in matlab and what to calculate the instantaneous phase for a specific band. I want to filter the signal into this range (using a bandpass filter) and then get the instantaneous phase. I know that there are problems using some filters with non-linear phase responses, is there any way to get around this? I have found some information online about back filtering the signal but it's still a little unclear. I'd like to avoid using wavelets (they're probably overkill here). Thanks.

Comment: Re: "back filtering": The "filtfilt" function runs a time series through a filter twice, once forwards and once backwards, so that the phase response cancels out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you resort to noncasual techniques (like the `filtfilt` suggested in the comment by nibot), you will *always* have some phase distortion. Linear phase FIRs with a delay D will add a phase of 2*pi*f*D, while nonlinear phase IIRs will add phase that is not linearly dependent on f.

In both cases, it is easy to compute the phase distortion (for example, use `freqz(num, den)` for IIRs) and account for that distortion when interpreting the resulting measurement. Of course, you'll have meaningless results when the phase changes significantly over the frequency range you are interested in - but that's a different issue.

Comment: I have seen examples of filtfilt() using IIR filters (specifically elliptical filters), but I was under the impression that the non-linear phase response meant even back filtering wouldn't work IIR filters.

Comment: filtfilt() should work even for IIR filters. As the MATLAB help page says: 'The result has precisely zero phase distortion and magnitude modified by the square of the filter's magnitude response'. There is some error with very long IIR responses, but otherwise it should be OK.
Of course you always just use FFT.